# Java: How to neatly create a data mapper utility for 200 fields not to repeat same checks again all over?

Tags: java, design-patterns, datamapper, boilerplate

Suppose we have scenario like following

```
if (!areEquals(empFraMD.getUserId(), empFraBubba.getUserId())) {
            empFraMD.setUserId(empFraBubba.getUserId());
            updated = true;
} 

if (!areEquals(empFraMD.getFirstName(), empFraBubba.getFirstName())){
            empFraMD.setFirstName(empFraBubba.getFirstName());
            updated = true;
}
 .........200 Times check for 200 different parameter. 150 Times String checks 20 times integer checks. 
 //EmpFraMD is current employees in Database and empFraBubba is employees fetched from SFTP 
    and both are objects of same class. The requirement here is just to update database 
    only in case difference
```

updated flag is just to set at end of code that if updated is true then setLastUpdated(now) in database.

Is there neat way to do this in Java using either design pattern or beans or some other way of transformation rather then write same chunk again and again?

Comment: You can use the patter [chain of responsibility](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/chain_of_responsibility_pattern.htm)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you know that two employees are equal and are the lists from the DB and the FTP ordered?

Comment: @GameDroids:  Fetch from FTP and with Employee ID, Fetch 1 Employee,,,, and So we always know DB Employee object has one. We create employee from FTP object. and compare both

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo: Not sure how this fits in above example.

Comment: @fatherazrael can you factored your code, inside your header and at the post of your code enter a call to your header. I think my solution can be applied to your code

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Detect whether object is updated or not? I am asking because this check `if (!areEquals(A.getUserId(), B.getUserId())) { A.setUserId(B.getUserId()); }` is pointless. If you remove the if-clause the result (of `A.setUserId(B.getUserId())`) will be still same anyway -- in case `A.userId` and `B.userId` are different `A` will receive `B`'s userId, and in case `A.userId` and `B.userId` are equal then `A.userId` will be overwritten with **same** value

Answer (score 1):

Well, It's pretty simple - write a comparator that will check a capability and will do the logic if it don't
As an option you can create your own annotation that will check the changes fact, so in case of the changes occurrence you will do your logic

```
 public T updateEntity(T entity) {
    try {
      Field[] declaredFields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
      for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        if (!field.isAnnotationPresent(IgnoreUpdating.class)) {
          Method readMethod = new PropertyDescriptor(field.getName(), this.getClass())
              .getReadMethod();
          if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
            updateColumn(entity, field.getName(), readMethod.invoke(this, (Object[]) null),
                Types.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
********************************************                
          } else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(BigDecimal.class)) {
            updateColumn(entity, field.getName(), readMethod.invoke(this, (Object[]) null),
                Types.DATA_TYPE_BIGDECIMAL);
          }
        }
      }
      return entity;
    } catch (IntrospectionException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
        | InvocationTargetException e) {
      log.error("updateEntity: "+e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new Exception(e.getMessage(),e);
    }   
  }

public static <T> T updateColumn(T entity, String columnName, Object value, String type) throws Exception {
    try {
      Method writeMethod = new PropertyDescriptor(columnName, entity.getClass()).getWriteMethod();
      if (value != null) {
        boolean isnull = false;
        ***********************
        if (isnull) {
          writeMethod.invoke(entity, (Object) null);
        } else {
          writeMethod.invoke(entity, value);
        }
      }
      return entity;
    } catch (IntrospectionException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
        | InvocationTargetException e) {
      log.error("updateColumn: "+e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new Exception(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
  }
```

And an invocation:

```
User user = model.updateEntity(userForUpdate);
```

Crate a class like this

```
public class UpdatableModel<T> {
  public T updateEntity(T entity);
  public static <T> T updateColumn(T entity, String columnName, Object value, String type) throws Exception;
}
```

implement them like i've showed below

BTW: 
probably you have pick up the [hibernate introcepters](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-interceptor)

Comment: Can you please provide example

Comment: Ouchhh... lemme understand and understand how to implement in my situation
Thanks BTW

Answer (score 1):

You can you json Serialization and Deserialization.
Consider below code:

```
public class UserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User fromDB = new User(10, "mca corner", "some address");
        User fromService = new User(10, "mca corner", "address changed");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jsonObjectFromDB = (JsonObject) gson.toJsonTree(fromDB, User.class);
        JsonObject jsonObjectfromService = (JsonObject) gson.toJsonTree(fromService, User.class);
        List<String> verifyFieldList = Arrays.asList("no", "name", "address");

        for (String field : verifyFieldList) {
            String dbValue = jsonObjectFromDB.get(field).getAsString();
            String serviceValue = jsonObjectfromService.get(field).getAsString();
            if (!serviceValue.equals(dbValue)) {
                jsonObjectFromDB.addProperty(field, serviceValue);
            }
        }
        User changedObject = gson.fromJson(jsonObjectFromDB, User.class);
    }
}

class User {
    int no;
    String name;
    String address;

    public User(int no, String name, String address) {
        super();
        this.no = no;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```